# Cumulative and density function of a random variable

Tags: probability

Let $X \sim \mathcal{U}([0,1])$. Calculate the cumulative function and the density function of $Y$ where
$$Y=\frac{2X}{1-X}$$

Comment: What you're doing is not legitimate. The probability $\mathbb{P}(Y < y)$ is equal to the integral of the density $f_Y$ over the interval $]-\infty,y]$. However, you do not know $f_Y$ yet since it is the aim of the exercise to compute it. Instead, you should do
$$\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) = \mathbb{P} \left(\frac{2X}{1-X} \leq y \right)  =\mathbb{P}(X \leq \ ? \ ).$$

Comment: That is correct. However, you have to be aware of the domain of $F_Y$. What about $y<0$?

Comment: I suppose the function have a zero at $x=0$ and an asymptote at $x=-2$. But what can I deduce from that?

Comment: I was just referring to the fact that $F_Y(y) = y/(2+y)$ for $y>0$ and $F_y(y) = 0$ for $y \leq 0$.

Comment: So am I correct to say that :
$$F_Y(y):=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\frac{y}{2+y} \quad & \text{if } y \ge 0 \\
0 \quad & \text{else}
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Are you sure? It is true that for $y \geq 0$,
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{2}{(2+y)^2}.$$
Furthermore,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f_y(y)dy = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(2+y)^2}dy = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\frac{2x}{1-x}$ is an increasing function on $(0,1)$, whose inverse is given by $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x}{x+2}$ so:
$$ \mathbb{P}[Y\leq t] = \mathbb{P}\left[X\leq \frac{t}{t+2}\right] $$
hence the cumulative distribution function of $Y$ is given by $\frac{x}{x+2}$ (it is supported on $\mathbb{R}^+$) and the density (also supported on $\mathbb{R}^+$) is given by $\frac{2}{(2+x)^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{x+2}$.

Answer (score 0):

I began by calculate the cumulative function, 
$$\begin{align}
F_Y(y)&=\mathbb{P}\left\{Y \leq y \right\} = \mathbb{P}\left\{\frac{2X}{1-X} \leq y \right\} = \mathbb{P}\left\{2X \leq y(1-X) \right\} = \mathbb{P}\left\{2X + yX \leq y \right\} \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left\{X(2+y) \leq y \right\} = \mathbb{P}\left\{X \leq \frac{y}{2+y} \right\} 
\end{align}$$
Thus,
$$F_Y(y):= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\dfrac{y}{y+2} \quad & \text{if } y \ge 0 \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{array}
\right.$$

And, to get the density function we derivate,
$$f_Y(y):=\dfrac{d}{dy}F_Y(y) = \dfrac{2}{(y+2)^2}$$

We can verify that this function is a density function by calculate :
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_Y(y) \cdot \mathcal{X}_{y \ge 0} \; dy = \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{2}{(y+2)^2} \; dy= 1$$